# Pulling just certain address from href tag in string always ends in .jpg

Tags: java, string

I have a string that always looks like so:

```
<a href="http://www.wcc.nrcs.usda.gov/nwcc/site?sitenum=XXX">Site Info</a>
```

...where sitenum=XXX will be any 3 or 4 or 5 number combo. I am trying to get just the sitenum from this string.

I figured this would give me the correct information for 3 numbers:

```
String src = de.substring(de.lastIndexOf("sitenum=") + 3);
```

However, that just takes 'sit' off of the 'sitenum=' and returns everything else like ">Site Info

I would like it to stop after getting the numbers and hitting the " that is found just after the numbers.

Am i using lastIndexOf incorrectly?

EDIT -- Answer worked for one url, but not another:

```
http://www.wcc.nrcs.usda.gov/cgibin/wygraph-multi.pl?state=NV&amp;wateryear=current&amp;stationidname=19K07S
```

I am trying to pull 'state' from this url, but it is not pulling state, just replacing letters in 'state'... Here is the code:

```
String state = de.substring(de.lastIndexOf("state=") + 2,
de.indexOf("&", de.lastIndexOf("state=")));
```

The state is always a 2 letter or the number 0... When I run this on my string I get:

```
ate=0
```

for example... I am confused on how this works?

EDIT EDIT! AH! I get it... so 2 needs to be 6 cause that is the amount of chars I am comparing to find the next char from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
String src = de.substring(de.lastIndexOf("sitenum=") + 8,de.indexOf("\"",de.lastIndexOf("sitenum=")));
```

Comment: That is the ticket. That stops at the " :) Thanks @Sandeep!

Comment: Ok, I'm kind of confused... The line of code you used above works great for that url above, so why not for another url? See edited answer above...

Answer (score 1):

Not the best way of doing it, but check if it is what you need:

```
String src = de.substring(de.lastIndexOf("sitenum=") + "sitenum=".length(), de.indexOf(">Site Info") - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are trying to get the text which is after `"sitenum="`, but `lastIndexOf("sitenum=")` will return the starting index of `"sitenum="` and not the text which you are expecting
try

```
int startindex = de.lastIndexOf("sitenum=") + "sitenum=".length();
int endIndex = de.lastIndexOf("\">Site Info</a>"); 
String src = de.substring(startindex ,endIndex);
```

Comment: That works great, but what if there are more than 3 numbers? How do I stop at the "?